# Calculating the mean elevation of a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, elevation

I have a DEM for a specific region and I want to know the mean elevation of this DEM (the average Z value of the whole raster). I'm working with QGIS with GRASS.

This seems like a really easy question, but I really couldn't find out how to do this (I'm a beginner, and the questions I found were all too specific).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Raster layer statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#raster-layer-statistics) should be your tool!

It gives an output report like this:

```
Analyzed file: C:/Users/.../DGM_5m.tif (band 1)

Minimum value: 0
Maximum value: 659
Range: 659
Sum: 8684914255
Mean value: 227.9959789092843
Standard deviation: 178.40250542293
Sum of the squares: 1212384106508.95
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!